# Convert iMacros script into another free automation tool like Kantu or Selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, imacros, browser-automation, kantu

I'm trying to create a script to perform mass actions on a personal account (context not relevant, I think). I figured a way to do it using this script for iMacros and it was working.

However, I needed to add a new variable to have a random delay between actions instead of having a fixed "WAIT SECONDS". Since I'm using the free version of iMacros, this doesn't work because it's using more than 3 variables :(

Now, problem is, I have no idea how to convert this script into another browser automation tool. Anyone can help me "translate it" to Kantu or Selenium, for example? Would it work? I'm aware that requesting opinion on tools is off-topic, but that's not my intention. I really don't care which program I use as long as it's free and it works. From what I've seen Kantu or Selenium are ok, but I don't understand how they work and I can't actually code (noob here) so I have no idea how to "translate" this to another platform. I need this for browser automation on Chrome (using a mac, if relevant).

Can anyone help me on this? Would really love to get this going but paying $99 for the premium version of iMacros is out of question as this is for personal use.

Thank you!

This is the script I have on iMacros:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

SET !VAR1 {{!LOOP}}
ADD !VAR1 1

TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:-utLf EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}

SET RANDOM EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*85 + 95); randomNumber;")

SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com/{{!VAR2}}
WAIT SECONDS={{RANDOM}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:BY3EC<SP><SP>_0mzm*
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:aOOlW<SP>-Cab_*

TAB CLOSE
```

Comment: If you are ok with doing this with selenium + python, I might be able to help you get started. I would need the real website + more detail action you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current Script can easily be converted to iMacros v10.0.x 'Free' for CR/FF using only 1 single Var, and you'll still have 2 Vars available...:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

SET !VAR1 {{!LOOP}}
ADD !VAR1 1

TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:-utLf EXTRACT=TXT

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*85 + 95); randomNumber;")

TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com/{{!EXTRACT}}
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:BY3EC<SP><SP>_0mzm*
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:aOOlW<SP>-Cab_*

TAB CLOSE
```

(And I've explained on the iMacros Forum how to use an "infinite" Nb of Vars with only 2 Vars..., trying to "lobby" against that Limitation that I find a bit useless and only nagging Users...)

Thread/Solution(s) referred to on the iMacros Forum:
- [Re: 2018/2019 and the Future of iMacros...](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30044&p=81870#p81870)
=> ... Where Users with some Account on the iMacros Forum are "encouraged" to support "my Crusade" against the **stupid** in my Opinion 3x Var Limitation for the 'Free' Editions...

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed! Just had to insert a "SET !EXTRACT NULL" after the "URL GOTO" part so that playing it in a loop worked and wohoo! :D

Comment: Oh, Thanks OP for accepting my Sol, I didn't really expect that, I hope you gave @Jim Grigoryan also a '+1' (like I did) for their excellent Conversion Guide...! - But hum, the 'SET !EXTRACT NULL' was not needed for the Script you had provided (Reason I had removed it) as you were not doing any other Extract than the one from your original Script, and '!EXTRACT' anyway automatically gets reset at the beginning of any new Loop...